# Transition property in removeClass() doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a problem with the transiton, if the method removeClass() is called.
If the removeClass method is called, the transition will not work.
If the addClass method is called, the transition works.

The code is executed when the (sticky) header reaches the "div"-tag.
When the "div"-tag is reached, the transition from the attribute "
.showElement.bkg-btn-orange-header" is executed .
But if you scroll up again, no transition will happen and the button will disappear directly.

Here is the code

JS-Code

```
$(document).scroll(function () {

    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        var heroShot= $('.section.triggerAddClass').offset().top - $("header").height();
        var footer= $('.section.triggerAddClass2').offset().top - $("header").height();
        if (y >= heroShot && footer >= y) {
            $('.bkg-btn-orange-header').addClass("showElement");
        } else {
            $('.bkg-btn-orange-header').removeClass("showElement");
        }
});
```

HTML-Code:

```
.....

<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <a href="#home" class="text-uppercase bkg-btn-orange-header">Test</a>
    </div>
   </li>
 </ul>

.....

<div class="section triggerAddClass">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="column">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS-Code

```
.section{
    padding-top: 11rem;
    padding-bottom: 11rem;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1
}

.triggerAddClass{
/*Empty*/
}

.triggerAddClass2{
/*Empty*/
}

.bkg-btn-orange-header {
    background-color: #e67e22;
    border-color: #e67e22;
    padding: 1.3rem 1.3rem;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}

.showElement.bkg-btn-orange-header {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

I'm hoping someone can help me. Thanks :)

Comment: I would try putting `-webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;` in a separate class that does not get removed and apply that class to the element as well.

Comment: It's because `visibility` gets set to `hidden` immediately. You need to create a special case for the transition of `visibility` where you delay it by the same amount of time as the duration of the `opacity` transition when you hide the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it disappears immediately is because its `visibility` gets set to `hidden` immediately. You need to delay `visibility: hidden` until the transition has completed. On the other hand, you need to have `visibility: visible` set immediately when showing the element or the fade-in transition wont work.

In other words, the delay needs to happen when the `showElement` class gets removed. To accomplish this, simply change your transition expression in the `.bkg-btn-orange-header` rule into:

```
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, visibility 0s 1s;
   transition: opacity 1s, visibility 0s 1s;
```

Keep the existing transition expression in your `.showElement.bkg-btn-orange-header` rule so that it overrides the previous one and makes `visibility: visible` set immediately as it should.